# Show current file name and parent directory in tabline of vim-airline

Tags: plugin-airline

I have the following directory structure

Current Directory

|--components

|--|--Artist

|--|--|--index.js

so i want to display "Artist/index.js" or "C/c/Artist/index.js" in my tabline in vim-airline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. These are the lines I added to the configuration file.

```
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#fnamemod = ':.'
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#fnamecollapse = 0
```

Comment: This is still not working for me

Comment: "It doesn't work" it not very helpful @Tillus, what is your configuration, what do you expect, and what do you see? It may be better to just ask a new question, considering this one is several years old.